# User profile properties Replication

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-property

I am having a problem with user profile property work phone. I don't want the work phone property to be displayed in userdisp.aspx so I unchecked the replicable property in user profile. However, it is still showing up in that page. Can anyone please tell me how to hide the work phone property?

Comment: did any one find the script for deleting replicated column from user info list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, by turning off replication, that means it won't update the field anymore.  That column and data will still live in the user information list on each site collection.  If you truly want it gone, you will need to write some code (.net or powershell) to remove that column in the user information list on each site collection.